# Grails - Asynchronous controller actions

Tags: grails, asynchronous, controller

I'm learning Grails and I have a grails application I'm working on.  I have a form that sends values to a grails controller. The controller can take awhile to deliver the output.  But I don't want the user to sit and wait before going to the results page.

I'd like the user to submit the form, then go to the results page.  The results page would load dynamic content from the controller once the grails controller has finished.  But in the mean time the results page could have other data for the user.

I'm not sure of the right solution here. Someone had told me about gpars, but in researching that, it seems a bit more advanced for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) queue, it is made to do exactly that -- asynchronous messaging.

Check out this article, which teaches you the basic concepts and how to use the Grails JMS plugin: http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-jms-grails

Comment: Thanks Elias.  I kinda got it working just now  with https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor however, I have a new thing.  But I like what you suggest. I'll look into it as well and compare with the plugin.

Comment: Cool! I hope you get to take a good look at JMS -- it'll probably scale easier.